# Texture displaying dark on one side

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm new to Blender so be easy on me.

I'm learning how to use textures and UV Mapping. I made a "wizards" hat and added a fabric texture to it. After seeing how it was stretching the texture, I put a seam down the middle of the hat (long ways) so that it is cut directly down the sides.

Now the texture is showing up nicely, however one side of the seam is much darker blue on one side than the other. Any advice on how to get the color similar on both sides is greatly appreciated!

[image: Wizards hat with one side darker than the other]

Answer (score 2):

Of course right after I finally post here I figure it out,

I changed the Color Space on the Normal Node to "Non-Color" and that fixed it!